# CakePHP 2 Code Coverage now says "No files to generate coverage for"

Tags: phpunit, cakephp-2.0, xdebug

My unit tests on CakePHP still run, but the code coverage has disappeared. All I get is "No files to generate coverage for".

Our application is currently running on CakePHP 2.10.15. I have PHPUnit 5.7 installed. Running PHP 7. I use the web runner for tests & coverage. I have XDebug 2.7.0beta1 running.

Did one of our recent upgrades break some sort of connection between Cake and PHPUnit?

Comment: Same problem here...

Answer (score 0):

Create a file *phpunit.xml* in your app folder:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/5.7/phpunit.xsd">

        <logging>
            <log type="coverage-text" target="tmp.txt" showOnlySummary="true"/>
        </logging>

        <testsuite name="default">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">tests</directory>
        </testsuite>    

        <filter>
            <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="false">                
                <!-- directories that you want in code coverage -->
                <directory suffix=".php">app/</directory> 
            </whitelist>
        </filter>

    </phpunit>
```

For me just adding this file like this worked just fine. For more information about this xml: https://phpunit.de/manual/5.7/en/appendixes.configuration.html

Be aware to include only the files and directories you need, otherwise it will became very slow.